# ModelState.IsValid is coming up as false and cannont create new entity in Database MVC5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an MVC5 application and when trying to create a new entity into a database the entity will not create as the model state is coming up as false and jumoing over the code. I have tried to put in breakpoints to see where the problem is coming from but no error is being generated and I cant figure it out
**This is what the controller is doing**

```
public ActionResult CreateRestaurant([Bind(Include = "RestaurantID,OwnerId,RestaurantName,RestaurantDescription,RestaurantPhoneNo, RestaurantEmailAddress, RestaurantAddress,County,Lat,Long,OpeningTime,ClosingTime,Rating,RestaurantType,FurtherDetails")] Restaurant restaurant)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //setting the owner of the restaurant to be the current logged in users id
            string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            restaurant.OwnerId = currentUserId;

            //set the logged on users email to be the email address of the restaurant.
            var email = User.Identity.GetUserName();
            restaurant.RestaurantEmailAddress = email;

            //Convert.ToString(restaurant.NoticeRequired);
            Convert.ToDouble(restaurant.Long);
            Convert.ToDouble(restaurant.Lat);
            db.Restaurants.Add(restaurant);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(restaurant);
    }
```

**This is my model**

```
// Class to manage a single Restaurant
    [Key]
    public int RestaurantID { get; set; }

    //To Test whos on the site
    public string OwnerId { get; set; }

    //Name
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a Restaurant Name")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Restaurant Name cannot be longer than 150 characters")]
    [Display(Name = "Restaurant Name")]
    public string RestaurantName { get; set; }


    //Discription
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Discription is too long")] //character remaining count
    public string RestaurantDescription { get; set; }

    //Phone Number
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a Phone Number")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    public string RestaurantPhoneNo { get; set; }

    //Email
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a valid Email Address")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string RestaurantEmailAddress { get; set; }

    //Address
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Address is too long")] //character remaining count
    public string RestaurantAddress { get; set; }

    //County
    [Display(Name = "County")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Please Select County")]
    public string County { get; set; }

    //Latidude
    [Display(Name = "Latitude Co-Ordinates")]
    //[StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Please enter Latidute Co-Ordinates")]
    public double Lat { get; set; }

    //Longitude
    [Display(Name = "Longitude Co-Ordinates")]
    //[StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Please enter Longitude Co-Ordinates")]      ADD BUTTON TO GET COORDS
    public double Long { get; set; }

    //Opening Time
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the restaurants opening time")]
    [Display(Name = "Opening Time")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}")]
    public DateTime OpeningTime { get; set; }

    //Closing Time
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the restaurants closing time")]
    [Display(Name = "Closing Time")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}")]
    public DateTime ClosingTime { get; set; }

    //Rating
    [Display(Name = "Rating")]
    public double Rating { get; set; }

    //Type
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Restaurant Type")]
    [Display(Name = "Restaurant Type")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public RestaurantType RestaurantType { get; set; }

    ////Amount of notice Required
    //[Display(Name = "Amount of Notice Required")]
    //[DataType(DataType.Text)]
    //public string NoticeRequired { get; set; }

    //Further Details        
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter any further details about your restaurant")]
    [Display(Name = "FurtherDetails")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string FurtherDetails { get; set; }

    //List of reservations for this restaurant 
    public virtual List<RestaurantReservationEvent> RestaurantBooking { get; set; }
}//end Restaurant
```

When I comment out the ModelState.IsValid line the entity is added ok

Comment: You are setting some required property values inside if block. Is `RestaurantEmailAddress` and `OwnerId` are filled when you are checking for state validity?

Comment: @RubenVardanyan I have added these in before the if block and it still jumps over it! Could it be something wrong with the datatype?

Comment: `ModelState` contains all the validation errors, so you can debug application and see what error message you get and which field's value causes the error

Comment: I scaffold-ed out the controller and view again and it fixed it

Answer (score 0):

According to your code it is seems that one of the rule in the tags of your "Model" class is not respected. Which probably put the Model in an Invalid state.

With a breakpoint or a logger, you should be able to see what's invalid in your model.